# Is there a way to have short names in GFlags?

Tags: gflags

I am trying to see if there is a way in gflags to have --server_configure and --sc map to same variable. Is there a way to have a short name for an option?

Comment: gflags.DEFINE_string('filename', None, 'Input file name', short_name='f')

Answer (score 2):

Found answer 
gflags.DEFINE_string('filename', None, 'Input file name', short_name='f')